# Backup file with .bak _before_ filename extension

Tags: shell, rename

I commonly backup config files on servers without version control like so:

```
# cp httpd.conf{,.bak}
# ls
httpd.conf    httpd.conf.bak
```

However, for files in the web root I take the time to carefully put the `.bak` before the filename extension so that the `.php` will remain and Apache will still send the file through the PHP interpreter if someone manages to guess or probe the server for such files:

```
$ cp index.php index.bak.php
$ ls
index.php    index.bak.php
```

Is there any way to use tab-completion and muscle memory to put the `.bak` before the filename extension? I have `Tab{}←,.bak` burned into muscle memory and I cannot use this nice "meat macro" on files in the web root.

Thanks.

Comment: The real answer is to use version control.

Comment: 100% Gilles! For one reason or another not every server is using version control, though I am trying to push in that direction.

Comment: If for some reason you cannot get version control now, get your backups out of the document root, and/or configure your httpd to deny requests to files with the .bak extension.

Comment: Yes, the 'backup' file is just a CMA for making a small change, which I _should_ rm as soon as I'm done. But you are right, I should configure .htaccess to deny .bak files. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might be as simple as

```
cp file.{ext,bak.ext}
```

bash {} expansion expands to all combinations (unlike [] expantion which lists existing files.  So it generates two file names.

The { .... , .... }
provides two options, so you get
file.ext and file.bak.ext

In your script you would use

```
cp $FILE.{$EXTENTION,bak.$EXTENTION}
```

And to break up the FILENAME into the two halves you can use

```
FILE=${FILENAME%.*}
EXTN=${FILENAME##*.}
```

${VAR%xxxxx} will return the left side of what is in VAR up to the matching pattern, in the case above the pattern is .* so you get everything except the last .*

${VAR##xxxxx} will return the right side of what is in VAR, after the matching pattern.  The double hash means get the biggest possible match, in case there is more than one possble match.

To make your script save, check for cases where after obtaining FILE and EXTENTION, that they are not the same thing.  This will happen in cases where the file name doesn't have an extention.

A sub-section of your script might look like this:

```
ls *html | while read FILENAME
do
    FILE=${FILENAME%.*}
    EXTN=${FILENAME##$FILE}
    cp $FILE{$EXTN,.bak$EXTN}
done
```

Comment: Note that the section where the sub-script tests to see if $FILE is the same as $EXTN simply squashes EXTN.  I notice there is a mistake, it requires that the . be inside the EXTENTION variable... A slight modification will take care of that automatically...

Comment: In this final version the script correctly handles files without an extention too.  It will generate two names, eg file and file.bak in those cases.

Comment: Why not just `cp file{,.bak}.ext` then?

Comment: @Bernhard Heh why didn't I think of that!?

Comment: @Bernard: Perfect! Now I need to find a standard (i.e. non-VIM) Bash shortcut to go back to the previous `.` character and I'll be in backup Nirvana.

Comment: I know that zsh allows for some very clever in-place substitutions on the command-line, though I'm not sure if it works like this exactly.  I think it is called global aliases .... maybe one of the local zsh gurus will pick this up?

Comment: I need this to work in standard Bash anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use a function:

```
backup()
  for i do
    case ${i##*/} in
      (?*.?*) cp -iv -- "$i" "${i%.*}.bak.${i##*.}";;
      (*) cp -iv -- "$i" "$i.bak"
    esac
  done
```

`${i##*/}` is the basename of `$i` (that is `$i` with everything up to the rightmost `/` removed), because we don't want to consider `bar/file` as the extension in `foo.bar/file`.

Then we check whether `$i` contains an extension, that is if it contains at least one `dot` character with characters on both sides (`?*` is *any one character* followed by *0 or more characters*, so it's *one or more characters*). We can't do `*.*` otherwise we'd backup `~/.bashrc` as `~/.bak.bashrc` for instance.

That syntax above is POSIX except for the `-v` (for *verbose*) option to `cp` which is a GNU extension also found in a few other implementations like BSDs'.

Then you can do things like:

```
backup foo.php bar.html baz<Tab>...
```

Or:

```
backup *.php
```

Without having to worry about losing data (`-i` will ask for confirmation before overwriting a file, see also the `-b` option with GNU `cp`) or not picking the right name.

Comment: Could you please break down the `(?*.?*)` and `(*)`? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I can't offhand think of a way to do this with tab completion, except possibly to also keep a copy of the file name without the extension, so you can add "bak.php" in one go. But my solution to this would be a small shell script, that takes a file name as input and copies it to "firstpart.bak.extension".

Comment: +1 for the shell script, which I'm trying to write into a BASH function as I'd like to take my `.bashrc` with me anyway.

Comment: Actually it'd probably be easier to call it "bak.firstpart.extension". Then you don't need to bother with parsing parts of name.

Comment: Thanks, but then the files won't sort together.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue for several unix systems with no source control with a requirement to make small changes fast. For cases like this I hit the file with a script to cut a time stamped copy of it to allow for quick recovery. ls shows the files with the versions date sorted by file name after it.

```
if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
   echo "File name required. Aborting."
   exit 1
fi

CDATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`
cp "$1" "$1-$CDATE"
echo File backed up to: $1-$CDATE
```

Usage:

```
VERS.sh httpd.conf
```

Output:

```
File backed up to: httpd.conf-2016-07-14-10-27
```